# How to read json data in typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, json, html

I want to read my data in JSON file then using it with typeahead.js here's [a link](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

if some one write any word like EnglishWords [Best] it will show him/she list all of the words that started with best or like best and select the word then show the description of the word
but I have no any idea because I am new in javascript and json thanks a lot :)

here's example of my json data file

```
    var Words = [
{"EnglishWords":"Best","Description":"an expression of good some this"},
 {"EnglishWords":"Best wishes","Description":"an expression of hope"},
{"EnglishWords":"Application","Description":"Computing a program or piece of software"},
-
-
-
-
-
-

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two separate things going on. One of is the autocomplete and the other some kind of word/phrase definition?

`typeahead.js` is only going to address the first part but it seems easy enough. Adapting the example from the github page, you'd want something like:

```
$('input.englishwords').typeahead({
  name: 'words',
  local: ['application', 'best', 'best wishes']
});
```

**EDIT:**

You'll have to parse your JSON object into an array or into an object that `typeahead` wants. Something like:

```
var typeList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Words.length; i++) {
    typeList.push(Words[i].EnglishWords);
}

then:

$('input.englishwords').typeahead({
  name: 'words',
  local: typeList
});
```